# Autodesk Forge model derivate properties returns empty collection

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Autodesk Forge model derivate properties returns empty collection, I am using the api

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/metadata/:guid/properties
```

to obtain the properties of a demp.dwg file but it returns the empty collection

```
{
"data": {
    "type": "properties",
    "collection": []
}    }
```

the call to get manifest

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/manifest

is as follows

```
{"urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YW50YW1pbmEvUHJ1ZWJhLmR3Zw",
"derivatives": [
    {
        "hasThumbnail": "true",
        "children": [
            {
                "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YW50YW1pbmEvUHJ1ZWJhLmR3Zw/output/properties.db",
                "role": "Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase",
                "mime": "application/autodesk-db",
                "guid": "cb73c076-d3cd-a725-754f-a64cd8c07648",
                "type": "resource",
                "status": "success"
            },
            {
                "guid": "fa729fe0-682e-c3b7-9662-9d88ce4b7b68",
                "type": "geometry",
                "role": "2d",
                "name": "4140",
                "viewableID": "4140",
                "status": "success",
                "hasThumbnail": "true",
                "progress": "complete",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YW50YW1pbmEvUHJ1ZWJhLmR3Zw/output/Prueba-4140_100.png",
                        "role": "thumbnail",
                        "mime": "image/png",
                        "guid": "816e2536-e012-c3d5-1b5a-fa4146daa077",
                        "type": "resource",
                        "resolution": [
                            100,
                            100
                        ],
                        "status": "success"
                    },
                    {
                        "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YW50YW1pbmEvUHJ1ZWJhLmR3Zw/output/Prueba-4140_200.png",
                        "role": "thumbnail",
                        "mime": "image/png",
                        "guid": "21cfc2dc-2b82-13d7-5f37-89aba22ce02d",
                        "type": "resource",
                        "resolution": [
                            200,
                            200
                        ],
                        "status": "success"
                    },
                    {
                        "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YW50YW1pbmEvUHJ1ZWJhLmR3Zw/output/Prueba-4140_400.png",
                        "role": "thumbnail",
                        "mime": "image/png",
                        "guid": "7c88e238-088a-f574-cbe8-b86397d67ef9",
                        "type": "resource",
                        "resolution": [
                            400,
                            400
                        ],
                        "status": "success"
                    },
                    {
                        "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YW50YW1pbmEvUHJ1ZWJhLmR3Zw/output/1b89b0d3-1560-00ab-c51e-7626cfe4cecb_f2d/primaryGraphics.f2d",
                        "role": "graphics",
                        "mime": "application/autodesk-f2d",
                        "guid": "56187d40-cf5c-e4d9-2fe7-a69210e2fcfe",
                        "type": "resource",
                        "status": "success"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "name": "Prueba.dwg",
        "progress": "complete",
        "outputType": "svf",
        "status": "success"
    }
],
"hasThumbnail": "true",
"progress": "complete",
"type": "manifest",
"region": "US",
"version": "1.0",
"status": "success" }
```

I can't get it to return the data in properties

Comment: When you loaded the model to Forge Viewer, is there any model objects and are their properties available in the properties panel? If yes, we may need to have a demo DWG file to diagnose. Please send it to forge.help AT autodesk.com if it is a confidential drawing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
in Forge viewer if the model and properties are displayed.
I will send the file to the indicated email
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem in the [GET properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET) endpoint that's specific to your DWG file. We've reported the issue to the engineering team, and will get back to you as soon as we have more information.

In the meantime, I'd suggest that you take a look at this blog post: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-design-metadata-without-viewer. It talks about other ways in which the model properties can be retrieved. In case of your specific DWG, I was able to retrieve the properties in the sqlite form without problems.